# asp.net website taking very long time to load after deploying it in hosting server

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, hosting

I am developing a website in asp.net. Site is running in localhost at satisfactory speed. As I deploy the site in hosting server with database stored in that hosting server, the website is taking very long time to load. Log In page loads instantly. After that, home page takes around 45 - 60 seconds to load. In home page, I have a small reporting section to perform calculation and grid view that has 70-80 rows. Data sets for both object are brought from stored procedure.

After debugging, I found out that

1. calculation for reporting takes around 1-2 seconds
2. and calling stored procedure and assigning it in data set takes almost 6-10 seconds
3. but binding the data set in grid view is taking very long time i.e. 30 -45 seconds.

From log in page to home page, I have used two session and i have set `<compilation debug="false"/>` in **web.config**. 
How can I improve the loading performance ?

The code for grid view is :::

```
installationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(companyInformation.Tables[0].Rows[0]           ["InstallationDate"]);       
employeeChecks = clsBLogic.GetAllChecksOfEmployee(tblEmployeeNo, installationDate,  currentDate);
SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
DataTable dt = employeeChecks.Tables[0];          
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = "Date" + " " + "desc";
gvEmployeeStatus.DataSource = dv;
gvEmployeeStatus.DataBind();
```

Any help? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: does the gridview has paging? and 70-80 rows for the page 1 of the gridview?

Can you share your gridview code,as 30-45 seconds is massive time for gridview to bind.

Comment: i have edited the code. I have paging as well as sorting in grid view..

Comment: how many records does datatable dt have?

Comment: i believe data table holds all the records in data set employeeChecks. So, dt holds 70 - 80 records

Comment: only reason i can see, is if the table has lot of records and paging is applied to show first 70 records on page then It can take lot of time.If it is the case then you can try sql paging, where you will get paged records from database instead of getting all at ones and binding to grid.

Comment: i had changed size of paging to 10 records per page.. still it is taking time.

Comment: can you try retrieving lesser records from stored procedure for eg top 5 or top 10 and see if it shows improvement.